# How to hold value for the state of a button for a timer?

Tags: c++, button, arduino, push, arduino-c++

I am making a timer with 3 push buttons with a 16x2 LCD screen on Arduino.   Obviously I want to press my start button once for the timer to count up until the stop button is pressed. I have a reset button that it is connected to the reset pin so I did not write code for it.

I have already been to the ladayada.com tutorial about button state I followed the instructions closely. I am still getting the wrong results.

```
signed short minutes, seconds;
char timeline[16];
int startPin = 7;
int stopPin = 6;
int buttonState1;
int buttonState2;
int oldState;
int currentState;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(startPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(stopPin,INPUT_PULLUP);

  buttonState1 = digitalRead(startPin);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(stopPin);

void loop() {
 currentState = digitalRead(startPin);
  if(currentState!= buttonState1){
  if(currentState==LOW){ 

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  sprintf(timeline,"%0.2d mins %0.2d secs", minutes, seconds);
  lcd.print(timeline);
  delay(1000);
  seconds++; 

 if (seconds == 60){
    seconds = 0;
    minutes ++; }
  }
  }

 if(buttonState2==LOW){
    delay(500);
    sprintf(timeline,"%0.2d mins %0.2d secs", minutes, seconds);
    }

 buttonState1 = currentState;
}
```

I expected the Arduino to save the state of the button and count up until the stop button is pressed. When the stop button is pressed it should display the time(current count) when it was pressed. Instead the Start button has to be pressed twice to count one second. I cannot even get to the logic of the stop button.

Comment: Your code is not C, it is C++.

Comment: Your code example is missing a close bracket ("}") at the end of the setup() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you press the start button only at the beginning of the program, why don't you just wait for a button action in `setup()`?

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(startPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(stopPin,INPUT_PULLUP);

  while (digitalRead(startPin) != LOW); // <- wait for button action
}
```

In `loop()`, you want to count up until the stop button is pressed. If you do hardware reset afterwards, you can just put the program into an infinite loop once the stop button has been pressed.

```cpp
void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  sprintf(timeline,"%0.2d mins %0.2d secs", minutes, seconds);
  lcd.print(timeline);
  delay(1000);

  seconds++; 

  if (seconds == 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes ++; 
  }

  if (digitalRead(stopPin) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    sprintf(timeline,"%0.2d mins %0.2d secs", minutes, seconds);
    while(true) {} // infinite loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know you could declare a while loop as a function in setup and pass in the parameter true or false when it is called, cool!